# Angular universal with HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, routes, universal, server-side-rendering

I am adding server-side rendering to Angular 4 app which uses HashLocationStrategy, and I am wondering if angular universal actually supports it. And if it does, I am curious, how the server knows which route is being requested?

Comment: No the server actually don't need to know it. In Angular app, the control should always be with angular. The default strategy that server uses to track in any given path is index.html. So, it is very essential in angular to set the error page, as if the user visit some child routes and angular is not initialized and won't find the router path in that case. So, to re-direct back to index.html page from where the angular can take over. Please let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: @Lambo14 It actually wouldn't be what they were looking for. The question is about the "serverside rendering" of a universal app. That means an "initial" request is actually "rendered" to the location rather than just plain redirect. Therefore the response to `/products` actually returns the rendered response to that location, and "then" the application bootstraps and the client routing takes over. So what is asked here is can that happen with `#/products`, which is a fragment and how does the server recognize that if it can.

Comment: The question really comes down to "is it possible for the server to see the fragment" in the URL. AFAIK, I don't think so. I would therefore surmise that "support" would be limited to defaulting to the "index" route and then letting the boostrapped application take over. Which of course it can "client side" since the fragment would be retained.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no. See: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/717

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4
>
> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
> identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
> the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional
> reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the
> retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not
> part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.
>
> The server is unaware of the hash by design. On the server you can
> generate the correct hash url for links but in terms of rendering a
> certain page you need another way to tell the server which page to
> generate